# Is there a workaround for the "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: n" error?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a pyspark job through spark-submit in which two large parquet tables are first being joined together before some additional logic is applied. Upon submission, all of the tasks fail and the logs indicate the following:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Kryo serialization failed: Buffer overflow. Available: 0, required: n*. To avoid this, increase spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max value
```

*n is just a variable that represents how much more memory is needed. This value depends on how much I set the `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` to.

I've increased this parameter's value to 2047 mb and I no longer hit the error and the job shows as "Complete" in the ApplicationMaster job tracker but the job still shows up as Running on the console as well as in yarn.

Context for the job being run:

For context, here is what I am doing. I am taking a very large list of URLs and joining them to the same exact list with the match criteria that the 2nd URL string is contained within the 1st URL string. For example: www.google.com would match www.google.com and www.google.com/1 and www.google.com/1/2 URL_Hierarachy = URL_1.join(URL_2, URL_1.url1 == URL_2.url2.substr(URL_1.numone,URL_1.nchar_url1),'left') where numone and nchar_url1 are used to define the length of the first URL. This will yield much more records than the initial 93M.

Comment: Since `spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max` sets the limit on the size of an object you attempt to serialize, I'm afraid there is something else going on in your case. Do you really have objects whose serialized form is > 2gb?

Answer (score 6):

This error is misleading, in the sense, what usually causes this error is you have low numbers of parallelism/unevenly distributed partitions then you are more likely to have a large size data to serialize/deserialize.

And at the same time spark2+ uses kryoserializer as the default serializer. you will get this error.

I would double-check the code of your join, partition of the dataframe, see if the large spark dataframe gets enough partition/ or is there any skewness in the data.

to increase the parallelism happens at the join

```
spark-submit --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=2000
```

to increase the partition of a given dataframe

```
df.repartition(2000)
```